# Socialite, google api error 'GET https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized'

Tags: laravel, google-api, laravel-socialite

I implemented social login with laravel socialite for facebook and google, and while it works for facebook for google it gives me this error

> Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
>   {
>   "error": {
>   "code": 401,
>   "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 (truncated...)

This is my login method:

```
   public function socialLogin($provider, $accessToken)
  {


        $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($accessToken);

        $user = Reader::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

        if (!$user) {

            $user = Reader::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
            ]);
        }

        if ($user) {
            $user->comment_count = DB::table(DB::raw('comments'))->where('author_id', $user->id)         
            ->count();

            return $user;

        }
        return $user;
    }
```

I get the access token but when it comes to this line

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($accessToken);
```

it shows the error from above. I have to mention that I'm working on an older laravel project that uses laravel 5.2 Can someone help?

Comment: userFromToken($accessToken)  <-- i dont think that method takes an access token.

Comment: @DalmTo but it does: "If you already have a valid access token for a user, you can retrieve their details using theuserFromToken method:"
```$user = Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token);```

Comment: Request is missing required authentication credential  <-- but its not its telling you that the authentication is missing.